# Unhandled exception at 0x797808F0 (ucrtbased.dll) in birinciodev.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c

I'm trying to run this program on Visual Studio 2019 in Win10. I have this debugging error on the line   `length = strlen(input);`
Program works fine with other compilers but I want to keep running it on VS. Could not figure it out why I have this issue.
This is also C based code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>

void rot(char* input) {

    int i;
    int length;
    length = strlen(input);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (isalpha(input[i])) {
            if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'm') {
                input[i] = input[i] + 13;
            }
            else if (input[i] >= 'n' && input[i] <= 'z') {
                input[i] = input[i] - 13;
            }
            else if (input[i] >= 'N' && input[i] <= 'Z') {
                input[i] = input[i] - 13;
            }
            else if (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'M') {
                input[i] = input[i] + 13;
            }

        }
        putchar(input[i]);

    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    rot(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you running the program? Did you actually pass in a command line arg?For starters update your code to protect against NULL `argv[1]` by checking `argc` first before attempting to use any of the `argv` values.

Comment: What is the string that fails? (i.e.) How do you invoke the program? (e.g.) `./myprogram abcdef`. Note that you do _not_ check for `argv[1]` being `NULL` which would happen _if_ the program were invoked with _no_ arguments (by accident from visual studio). In `main`, try: `if (argc < 2) { printf("no argument\n"); exit(1); }` as the first thing.